# How can I scroll inside a popup using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I need to scroll a popup. I know only `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2080)")` - doesn't work.

i've tryed `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2080)")`, but this command scrolls all window, not a popup.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to scroll down a popup window containing some elements, is to scroll to the last element.

```
followers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-labelledby]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', followers[-1])
```

Change `[-1]` to something else if you want to scroll to another element, for example `[4]` to scroll to the fifth element.